# How to increase the value of a number to the next multiple of 10, 100, 1000, 10,000 and so on

Tags: javascript, math, max

You'll have to forgive the phrasing of this question, I'm sure there's a better, more succinct way to ask it, but I don't know it.

Let's say I have a graph, and all the y-axis values are

`[0,4,5,3,2,5,6]`

The maximum value is six. So I would like the Y-Scale to be labeled from 0 to 10.

Given the following values

`[33,26,54,23,86,23]`

The maximum value is 86, so I would like the Y-Scale to go from 0 to 90.

Now let's say I have the following values

`[98,253,87, 876,263]`

The max is 876,so the Y-scale should go from 0 to 900

Now I have created the following function that should give me all the max y-scale values I need so far.

```
function padMaxValue(value){
        for(var i = 1; i < 1000000000000000000; i = i * 10){
            var decimalValue = value / i;

            if(value === i){
                return i;
            }

            if(decimalValue < 1 && decimalValue > 0.09){
                return i;
            }

        }
    }
```

However, given the following values

[99,123,82,189,45]

My function would set the y-scale max to `1000`. But the max should really be 200. I realise that what I really need is a smarter way to increase the value of `i` instead of just multiplying it by 10. I need to be able to increase the value of i by 10, all the way up to 100. Then increase it by 100, all the way up to 1000. Then increase it by 1000, all the way up to 10,000 and so on.

I feel like there should be some neat and tidy mathematical way to do this. And I also feel that the `1000000000000000000` number I have in the for loop betrays my ignorance of mathematics.

Anyhoot, that's the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider two steps: 1. get min and max values of your data. 2. rounding them as you desire.

Comment: Why does 86 go to 100 not 90 if 876 goes to 900 not 1000?

Comment: good point. Just felt natural, humans are irrational.

Comment: Do you want consistent rules or an exception for low values? Either way you should update your question to reflect your choice. All answers I have tested fails at your second test-case.

Comment: The answers you have are good from an implementation/stackoverflow perspective, but you should probably also head over to the ux (User Experience) exchange to see if you really *want* to do this. My choice would be a small array of hand-picked, psychologically comforable, ux-driven values. This will be denser at the lower end of the scale than at the top end. You'd then pick the lowest of these, scaled by a power of 10, that can fit your data.

Comment: `s/graph/plot/` ? :-)

Comment: This problem has already been solved in libraries such as d3.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There is no need to go into the land of strings, which could be awkward if you ever had a decimal value.

```
function RoundedMax(a) {
    var mx = Math.max.apply(Math, a);
    if (mx == 0) {return 0};
    var size = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(mx)) / Math.LN10);
    var magnitude = Math.pow(10, size);
    var yMax = Math.ceil(mx / magnitude) * magnitude;
    return yMax;
}

function RoundedMin(a) {
    var mn = Math.min.apply(Math, a);
    if (mn == 0) {return 0};
    var size = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(mn)) / Math.LN10);
    var magnitude = Math.pow(10, size);
    var yMin = Math.floor(mn / magnitude) * magnitude;
    return yMin;
}

var arr = [-9.9,-1.23,-8.2,-2.01,-4.5,0];
document.write(RoundedMax(arr) + " " + RoundedMin(arr));
```

Outputs: `0 -10`.

**EDIT** Updated in view of the comments. Now works even in IE8.

---

Now (2023) that all current browsers support ECMAScript 6:

```
function RoundedMax(a) {
    var mx = Math.max.apply(Math, a);
    if (mx == 0) {return 0};
    var size = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(mx)));
    var magnitude = Math.pow(10, size);
    var yMax = Math.ceil(mx / magnitude) * magnitude;
    return yMax;
}

function RoundedMin(a) {
    var mn = Math.min.apply(Math, a);
    if (mn == 0) {return 0};
    var size = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(mn)));
    var magnitude = Math.pow(10, size);
    var yMin = Math.floor(mn / magnitude) * magnitude;
    return yMin;
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the first answer to use logarithms, not something silly like string length.

Comment: Note: `Math.log10()` is part of the ECMAScript 6 draft, so it's not widely supported yet. However, you can still calculate a base 10 logarithm by doing `Math.log(x) / Math.LN10`.

Comment: @rhino Thank you for that information, I only tested it in FF33. Truth be told, I created the code in VB.NET and then translated it to JS.

Comment: Why not use `abs` instead of going through the `sign` variable?

Comment: @coredump I did have a note in there about that. I didn't expect the answer to be so popular, but as it is, I have also incorporated rhino's point about `Math.log10`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Great. I know this is not codereview.stackexchange.com, but I'll leave just one minor observation (don't feel obliged to modify the answer): `RoundedMax` and `RoundedMin` are almost exactly the same and differ by only 2 characters (replace "ax" by "in" :-). I would certainly try to factorize them into a single function in actual code. That being said, I upvoted your answer and like it as it is.

Comment: @coredump Actually there's a second difference: `floor` vs. `ceil` near the end of each function. Factoring out the common stuff would have made that a little more obvious, but perhaps at the expense of too much complexity.

Comment: @DavidK I should have ran `diff`. I agree that this kind of code duplication is hard to factorize while preserving clarity.

Comment: I'm getting 6 for the first use case instead of 10 [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/saloriseve/1/edit?html,output).  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Tom Excellent point. You have done nothing wrong. The OP has actually specified two different behaviours, which I did not spot. To get 6 to result in a value of 10, you can use `var yMax = Math.ceil(mx * Math.pow(10, -size - 1)) * Math.pow(10, size + 1);`.

Comment: `Math.log(1000)/Math.LN10` returns `2.9999999999999996` for me in chrome while `Math.log10(1000)` returns `3`. Sending the result directly to Math.floor without compensating for machine epsilon makes the difference between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 23):

I don't like math, so here is a pretty simple/hilarious string-manipulation solution:

Find the maximum value:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [98,253,87, 876,263]); // 876
```

Take its first character

```
var c = max.toString()[0] // "8"
```

Make it an integer and add 1

```
c = (c | 0) + 1 // 9
```

Convert it back to a string:

```
c = c.toString() // "9"
```

Add N - 1 zeros to it, where N is the length of your original number:

```
c += Array(max.toString().length).join("0") // "900"
```

Convert it back to an integer:

```
c = (c | 0) // 900
```

Done!

---

Seriously though, [use math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662625/229044).

Comment: Very clever.  Didn't even think about doing string manipulation.

Comment: I love it, but going to go with entropics answer for fear I'll be laughed out of a job.

Comment: String representations will become `NNe+XX`-formatted for very large values. I'd suggest `Math.floor(Math.log10(max))` for reliably detecting number of digits instead of `max.toString().length`. (Though at that size, we start losing floating point precision anyway, so I guess there's problems all around.)

Answer (score 11):

I believe this would do the trick for you:

```
var data = [98, 253, 87, 876, 263, -155];
var max = Math.max.apply(null, data); // 
var factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(max)) / Math.LN10)); 
if (factor == 0) { factor = 1; }                  
var magnitude = Math.ceil(max / (factor * 1.00)) * factor;
```

Basically what's happening above is the following:

1. Find the maximum of the sample
2. Get the maximum values length, then raise it to a power of 10 i.e. 345, length = 3, so factor is 100
3. Make sure we don't divide by 0
4. Divide the maximum number by the factor to get a decimal, and take the ceiling of that number, then multiply it back by the factor to get the right number of 0s.

**UPDATE:** If you want to find the minimum value (for negative values), just flip the `Math.ceil` to `Math.floor`.  You also have to take the absolute value of the minimum to make sure you don't count the negative character as part of the string.

```
var data = [98, 253, 87, 876, 263, -155];
var min = Math.min.apply(null, data);
var factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(max)) / Math.LN10));
if (factor == 0) { factor = 1; }
var mag = Math.floor(min / (factor * 1.00)) * factor //  mag = -200;
```

**UPDATE 2:** As many people have said in the comments, we shouldn't be using string manipulation.  I updated the code to use logarithms instead.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here in the last line, but `Math.pow(10, Math.max(max.length - 1, 1)) * (max[0] | 0 + 1)`?

Comment: I too have no idea what's happening here but... yoink!

Comment: @meagar: maybe make an answer explaining what that does? becuase I don't follow. Also, entropic, you should explain what's happening a bit more to make the answer more helpful.

Comment: @ColinDeClue added the explanation

Comment: This works great for my needs, however - at the risk of sounding ungrateful - I notice it doesn't work for values less that 1. I'm not complaining though, I don't need that behaviour.

Comment: @gargantaun Updated the code for minimum values as well.

Comment: Why not using logarithm instead of that `(max + "").length` ? Mathematically you would use something like `floor(log(abs(max))) + 1` (+ the handling of the sign)/ That should also work for values less than 1

Comment: The truly mathematical way to do this would be to get the maximum value, convert it to scientific notation, take the ceiling of the mantissa (the coefficient), and normalize back to regular notation. Javascript apparently provides a `toExponential()` function, but since it outputs a string, you'd end up doing string manip anyway.

Comment: As Andrew Morton mentions, anything working from string lengths is asking for trouble as soon as you are not working with integers.

Comment: Don't follow this answer.  Whenever you are working with numbers and your proposed answer involve going via a string representation to get at a mathematical property of the number chances are that you are doing it wrong.  In this case; the log function exists and is the correct tool for this job.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung No.  While your suggestion is better than the answer the correct procedure is in the comment by Synxis immidiately preceeding yours.

Answer (score 3):

I wound up with:

```
function getGraphRange(data)
{
    var max=Math.max.apply(null, data);
    var min=Math.min.apply(null, data);
    var maxDigits=max.toString().length;
    var minDigits=min.toString().length;
    var maxD=Math.pow(10,Math.max((maxDigits-1),1));
    var minD=Math.pow(10,Math.max((minDigits-1),1));
    var maxR=(Math.ceil(max/maxD)*maxD);
    var minR=(Math.floor(min/minD)*minD);
    return [minR,maxR];
}
alert(getGraphRange([11, 20, 345, 99]).join(' - '));//10-400
alert(getGraphRange([0,4,5,3,2,5,6]).join(' - '));//0-10
alert(getGraphRange([98,253,87,876,263]).join(' - '));//80-900
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4xjs9na/

Comment: It returns min max values. Nice touch.

Comment: Yeah, but the string manipulation approach would need some adjustments to work with negative numbers due to the `-` or floating point numbers which contain a `.`

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here. I have used while loop to solve the problem. The function is very fast and it can return value in less than a second for even a very large number.

```
function padMaxValue(value)
{
    var i = 10;
    var counter = 0;
    var roundMax = 10;
    var copyValue = value;
    //If the value is negative, convert copyValue to positive
    if(value < 0) copyValue *= -1;
    while(roundMax <= copyValue)
    {
        roundMax += i;
        counter++;
        if(counter == 9)
        {
            i *= 10;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    if(value < 0) roundMax *= -1;
    return roundMax;
}
document.write(padMaxValue(8) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(77) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(889.65) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(-880.65) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(-765889.65) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(7888.88) + "<br>");
document.write(padMaxValue(88999887788899.099887) + "<br>");
```

Output:

10

80

900

-900

-800000

8000

90000000000000

Answer (score -1):

I am not much of Math person but i take programming seriously! I came up with this solution!

```
function getMax(max){
    var mCopy = max;
    var d=1;//Assuming everything is greater than 10, 
    while(Math.floor(mCopy) > 10){//if the number is not one digited 
        mCopy /= Math.pow(10,d);
        d++;
    }
    d--;//back one digit
    if(d<1)
       d++;
    if((Math.floor(max / Math.pow(10,d))*Math.pow(10,d))==max)
       return max;
    return Math.floor(max / Math.pow(10,d))*Math.pow(10,d) + Math.pow(10,d);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the given answers are overly complicated. Here is an anonymous function that can be used in MATLAB:

```
next = @(x,n) ceil(x/n)*n;

>> next(11,10)    
ans =    
    20 %# 20 is the next "10" after "11")

>> next(110,100)    
ans =    
   200 %# 200 is the next "100" after "110"

>> next([98,253,87, 876,263],100)    
ans =    
   100   300   100   900   300
```

`x` is the number that should be processed and `n` is the requested step size.

**edit**
Automation of determining the next order of magnitude is also possible

```
>> nextOrder = @(x) ceil(x/10.^ceil(log10(x))) * 10.^ceil(log10(x));

>> nextOrder([98,253,87,876,263])    
ans =    
         100        1000         100        1000        1000
```

Comment: But that isn't JavaScript, which is a requirement for a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw the JavaScript tag.